# Formulario con checkboxes - No enviar los "no checked"

Tags: php, formularios, checkbox

Tengo un formulario en una página html con varios checkboxes, de los cuales *(al ser opciones)* no es necesario que sean marcados, pero en el email me llegan los espacios en blanco entre "checked" & "checked":

---

```
$opcion1 .= $_POST['marcador1'];
$opcion2 .= $_POST['marcador2'];
$opcion3 .= $_POST['marcador3'];
$opcion4 .= $_POST['marcador4'];
```

---

Cuando el usuario marca la **opción 1** y la **opción 4** yo recibo el email con dos lineas en blanco:

---

```
Opcion 1
   // Espacio en blanco
   // Espacio en blanco
Opcion 4
```

---

¿Cuál es el código en el php que evalúa los checkboxes y **elimina** los no marcados, es decir: **no los envía al email**, para así quitar los saltos de línea inútiles en el cuerpo del mensaje?

Comment: Pues en tu código PHP filtras los datos y detectas si el checkbox está vacío, pero de todos modos deberías compartir también tu código HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador1 . " \r\n";` ahí tienes un espacio en blanco (`" "`) y los saltos de línea (`\r\n`)

Sustituye

```
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador1 . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador2 . " \r\n";
```

por

```
if($marcador1 != ""){
   $cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador1 . " \r\n";
}
if($marcador2 != ""){
   $cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador2 . " \r\n";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @PriNcee Funciona perfectamente... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la función `isset()`. Esta función evalua si la variable ha sido definida. Si la variable no ha sido definida pues no la ocupes o no la uses cuando estas enviando el correo. la funcion devuelve un booleano.

```
if(isset( $_POST['marcador1']){
  $opcion1 = $_POST['marcador1'];
}
if(isset( $_POST['marcador2']){
  $opcion2 = $_POST['marcador2'];
}
if(isset( $_POST['marcador3']){
  $opcion3 = $_POST['marcador3'];
}
if(isset( $_POST['marcador4']){
  $opcion4 = $_POST['marcador4'];
}
```

y solo no tomes los que no estan definidos.

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta considera añadir un ejemplo práctico. Aunque los ejemplos puedan parecer demasiado obvios no hay que menospreciarlos... pueden ser de utilidad a futuros visitantes.

Comment: Por qué tiene votos negativos si esta respuesta es útil?

Comment: @user2930137 vete tu a saber. A mi se me ocurre que quizas sea porque el ejemplo es claramente erróneo ya que sobreescribe todo el rato `$opcion1`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias amigos.
Pues tengo algo así (22 ckeckboxes y ninguno es obligatorio), y es lo que comentaba: Si el visitante marca la opción **2**, la **13** y la **22**, en el email me llegan **saltos de lineas intermedios** (los ckeckboxes unchecked), y es muy feo como queda el cuerpo del mensaje.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign("url.html");
</script>';
//---------
$opcion1 .= $_POST['marcador1'];
$opcion2 .= $_POST['marcador2'];
$opcion3 .= $_POST['marcador3'];
$opcion4 .= $_POST['marcador4'];
.
.
$opcion22 .= $_POST['marcador22'];
//---------
$nombre .= $_POST['nombre'];
$mail .= $_POST['email'];
$mensaje .= $_POST['mensaje'];
//---------
$header .= 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";
//---------
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Enviado por: " . $nombre . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "E-Mail: " . $mail . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= "Mensaje:" . " \r\n\r\n";
//---------
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador1 . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador2 . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador3 . " \r\n";
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador4 . " \r\n";
.
.
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador22 . " \r\n\r\n";
//----------
// Aquí el codigo sigue con otros $cuerpo_mensaje adicionales
//----------
$para = 'aqui_el_correo';
$asunto = 'el_asunto';
mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($cuerpo_mensaje), $header, '-faqui_el_correo');
}
?>
```

¿Donde meto todos los isset...?

```
if(isset( $_POST['marcador x']){
  $opcion x = $_POST['marcador x'];
}
```

**Nótese que solo quiero evitar recibir los unchecked indicados:**

```
$cuerpo_mensaje .= " " . $marcador x . " \r\n";
```

No me aclaro mucho con ésto (php no es lo mio).

Muchas gracias!

Comment: te contesto con un comentario arriba para que lo veas mejor